# How to make the navigation and status bar light without it being deprecated in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, statusbar, navigationbar

I'm making the Navigation bar light and status bar light themed in Kotlin with this code:

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.white)
window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.white)
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```

With window being:

```
val window: Window = this@MainActivity.window
```

This works perfectly, except for the fact that `systemUiVisibility` is deprecated, so is `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`.

So what is the new way of doing this if the method I'm using is deprecated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)

> Use WindowInsetsController#APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS instead

The way to go about this in the activity would be to access the `WindowInsetsController` and then use the `setSystemBarsAppearance` method to set the flags. Like so:

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    window.insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(
        WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS or WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS,
        WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS
    )
} else {
     @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
     window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
         View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
}
```